# Is there a way to set app icons to top menu bar. (near clock,charge etc)

Tags: icons, menu

I want to see my favorite applications on top menu bar. Is there a way to set app icons to top menu bar. (near clock,charge etc). in ubuntu 11.10

Answer (score 0):

Yes absolutely just drag and drop your favorite application to the "top menu" bar. also from the right click menu on the bar you will find an option to add ( i'm not working know on my Ubuntu so i can't give the exact steps to do it).

Comment: not working for 11.10. drag and drop was on old releases :)